# Xcode-beta can not be opened while it is being updated

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using `Xcode beta 8.1 beta 2` for development.
It was working fine for me.
But suddenly, it closed and I tried to open it prompted me this message:

> Xcode-beta can not be opened while it is being updated.

[image]

When will it be resolved?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Open activity monitor (`/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app`), switch to the CPU tab and search for `storedownloadd`. If that process is present and you aren't downloading anything using the Mac App Store, you can kill it.

Comment: Whenever I do this another one instantly pops up and I still can't start XCode!  Annoying!  I was trying to teach a class today and couldn't use my laptop...

Comment: Didn't work for me. Mac App Store only gives the option to update it.

Comment: Killing a ongoing process is not a good solution. Better solution is here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/58096678/1084174

Answer (score 29):

Faced the same issue and here is the solution to open Xcode.

Go to **Application** folder -> find **Xcode** -> Right click and select "**Show Package Content**" -> Go to **Content** -> **MacOS** -> Double click **Xcode** (Unix excecutable file).

It worked for me!

Comment: it's not a permanent soluion

Comment: Great as a temporary solution. I was literally in the middle fixing a critical bug on a large scale app, and Xcode just suddenly decided it's time to update and quit on its own. Crazy how Apple doesn't take these things into consideration and don't even ask you if you want to update.

Comment: while no solution worked for me until xcode actually gets updated. This temporary solution keeps things going for me. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

tried @Rick's solution didn't work. I ended up restarting my machine which fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

#### Please follow the steps below,

```
1. Open App Store app in you Mac
2. Select Updates tab
3. Look Xcode is in Pending section
4. Stop (Sometime start Update and then Stop)
```

You will be able to open the app now onwards.

> Note: That is applicable not only for Xcode but also for any app which is not opening due to updating.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an AppStore bug.

Check the link for the fix: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126288/xcode-5-1-wont-launch-being-updated-but-already-installed

Answer (score 1):

Did you update your system to the newest version? If not, please do so. Then try opening XCode. I believe it will work out with this problem. Otherwise, you need to re-install your Xcode.

Comment: I think the asker was asking "any suggestions", and I update my system and, I can reopen my Xcode...even I didn't know what kind bug is that...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I noticed that this warning is revealed when there is a continuing install in AppStore (it was itunes for me and Xcode 8.2.1).

Try to cancel download or just wait for it to be complete. Then xcode will again be available to work on.

Answer (score 1):

Open Launchpad, scroll to XCode and if it shows the download progress just wait for completion [image: XCode update downloading]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem for a while and the ONLY thing that worked for me was to uninstall XCode and download it again.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue as I had.
As my Mac running out of space, I deleted some Simulators(from `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/`) which I don't need/use. When I tried to start Xcode after cleanup then I got OP's issue.

Able to launch Xcode after restarting the system. So try restarting system first if that doesn't work, try @Sazzad's or accepted answer.